# Vue Component is not visible in <template> html tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vue.js

I have a simple problem but I can't find any reliable answer.

So here is what I want to do. The code is simplified for clarity.

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div id='app'>
    <template>
        <p>Here is the app: {{message}}</p>
        @Html.Partial("_Component")
    </template>
</div>


<script> 
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: "App works!"
        }
    });
</script>
```

And `_Component.cshtml` file:

```
<my-component inline-template>
            <div>
                <p><button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add One More Click</button></p>
                <p>The button has been clicked {{ counter }} times</p>
            </div>
        </my-component>

        <script>
            Vue.component('my-component',
                {
                    data: function () {
                        return {
                            counter: 1
                        }
                    }
                });
        </script>
```

Problem with this code is that `my-component` is not rendering. Overall, I'm working in project of `asp.net mvc` application and its required to use `template` tag.

If I remove this tag, the page is a mess until it's rendered.

Is there any solution or workaround to be able to see component in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the component in the wrong place. Should be like this

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div id='app'>
    <template>
        <p>Here is the app: {{message}}</p>
        <my-component inline-template>
            <div>
                <p><button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add One More Click</button></p>
                <p>The button has been clicked {{ counter }} times</p>
            </div>
        </my-component>
    </template>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('my-component', {
    data: function () {
      return {
        counter: 1
      }
    }
  });

  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: "App works!"
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, It's correct. The thing is I can't do that, in Our system component and script is in separate file and called by asp.net mvc's  ```Html.Partial```  ... I will edit an question then.